# Using std::regex to filter input

Tags: c++, regex

I have an ugly mess of a string, that is composed of several URIs.

```
:/SymbolStandards/JMSymbology/MIL_STD_2525D_Symbols/0_301_0.svg,:/SymbolStandards/JMSymbology/MIL_STD_2525D_Symbols/02011.svg,:/SymbolStandards/JMSymbology/MIL_STD_2525D_Symbols/02012.svg,:/SymbolStandards/JMSymbology/MIL_STD_2525D_Symbols/02110000.svg
```

What I would like to do is strip out every occurrence of the characters `:/.,`, so I can have a single string that would be a valid filename.

I've written this simple regex expression in order to do jus that: `[^(:/,.)]`
It seems to be the correct regex expression, according to http://www.regexpal.com/.

However, when I run the following C++ code, I do not get back what I was expecting(just alphanumeric characters and underscores), I just get back the first alphanumeric character in the sequence: `S`.

What am I doing incorrectly with std::regex, or is my regex expression off?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <regex>
#include <string>

static const std::string filenames {R"(:/SymbolStandards/JMSymbology/MIL_STD_2525D_Symbols/0_301_0.svg,:/SymbolStandards/JMSymbology/MIL_STD_2525D_Symbols/02011.svg,:/SymbolStandards/JMSymbology/MIL_STD_2525D_Symbols/02012.svg,:/SymbolStandards/JMSymbology/MIL_STD_2525D_Symbols/02110000.svg)"};
static const std::regex filename_extractor("[^(:/,.)]");

int main() {
    std::smatch filename_match;
    if(std::regex_search(filenames, filename_match, filename_extractor))
    {
        std::cout << "Number of filenames: " << filename_match.size() << std::endl;
        for(std::size_t i = 0; i < filename_match.size(); ++i)
        {
            std::cout << i << ": " << filename_match[i] << std::endl;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I suspect you want `std::regex_replace` but this is probably better not using regex at all. Maybe look at [std::remove_if](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove).

Comment: I don't understand. Your string contains `,:/`, not `:/,`? Can't you split on that instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `size()` of `std::smatch` returns the number of sub-expression + 1 (with `(` and `)`, which you do not have).

## Solution

You need to call [`std::regex_search`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/regex_search#Notes) repeatedly, or use [`std::regex_iterator`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/regex_iterator).

In addition, your regex actually searched only for a single character.
You need to use a `+` to search for the longest character sequences: `[^(:/,.)]+`.

Here is your code, incorporating the example from [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/regex_iterator):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <regex>
#include <string>

static const std::string filenames {R"(:/SymbolStandards/JMSymbology/MIL_STD_2525D_Symbols/0_301_0.svg,:/SymbolStandards/JMSymbology/MIL_STD_2525D_Symbols/02011.svg,:/SymbolStandards/JMSymbology/MIL_STD_2525D_Symbols/02012.svg,:/SymbolStandards/JMSymbology/MIL_STD_2525D_Symbols/02110000.svg)"};
static const std::regex filename_extractor("[^(:/,.)]+");

int main() {
    auto files_begin = std::sregex_iterator(filenames.begin(), filenames.end(), filename_extractor);

    for (auto i = files_begin; i != std::sregex_iterator(); ++i) {
        std::string filename = i->str(); 
        std::cout << filename << '\n';
    }   

    return 0;
}
```

However, this returns also the intermediate "directories".
If you use the regex `[^(:,)]+`, you get the result *I* would expect you wanted to have:

```
/SymbolStandards/JMSymbology/MIL_STD_2525D_Symbols/0_301_0.svg
/SymbolStandards/JMSymbology/MIL_STD_2525D_Symbols/02011.svg
/SymbolStandards/JMSymbology/MIL_STD_2525D_Symbols/02012.svg
/SymbolStandards/JMSymbology/MIL_STD_2525D_Symbols/02110000.svg
```

## Your problem explained

`std::regex_search` searches only for the *first* occurence of the regular expression, and any sub-expressions within.

For example, the expression `ab([cd])([ef])` will match the string `xxabcfxxabdef`.
The first match is the part `abcf`, with `c` being the match for the first sub-expression `[cd]` and `e` being the match for the second sub-expression `[ef]`.

The second match is the part `abde` (not `abdef`!), where `e` is the match for the second sub-expression.

With `std::regex_search`, you search for the first match, and the matcher returns you the complete *first* match and the matches for the sub-expressions.
If you want to find further matches, you have to start the search from the rest of the string (`std::smatch::suffix()`).

In addition, the regex `[ef]` matches only a single character. `[ef]+` would match the longest sequence of `e`s and `f`s.
Thus, the match for the second sub-expression of `ab([cd])([ef])` for the target string above would match `ef`, and not just `e`.

Answer (score 2):

I think `std::regex_replace` is what you need here:

```
#include <regex>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

const std::string filenames {R"(:/MIL_STD/0_3.svg,:/SS/2525D/02011.svg)"};
const std::regex filename_extractor("[(:/,.)]");

int main()
{
    std::string r;

    std::regex_replace(std::back_inserter(r),
        filenames.begin(), filenames.end(), filename_extractor, "");

    std::cout << "before: " << filenames << '\n';
    std::cout << " after: " << r << '\n';
}
```

However I think regex is probably overkill for removing characters you can do this more efficiently with [std::remove_copy_if](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove_copy):

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

const std::string filenames {R"(:/MIL_STD/0_3.svg,:/SS/2525D/02011.svg)"};
const std::string filename_extractor("(:/,.)");

int main()
{
    std::string r;

    std::remove_copy_if(filenames.begin(), filenames.end(),
        std::back_inserter(r), [](char c)
    {
        return filename_extractor.find(c) != std::string::npos;
    });

    std::cout << "before: " << filenames << '\n';
    std::cout << " after: " << r << '\n';
}
```